# Convert a byte array to base64 for blackberry using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

How do I convert a byte array to a base64 encoded string using the BlackBerry plug-in for Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the BlackBerry JDE API documentation for net.rim.device.api.io.Base64OutputStream

Answer (score 0):

The best source of information is from one of the following:

1. [Commons Apache Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)
2. [ostermiller.org/utils/Base64.html](http://ostermiller.org/utils/Base64.html)

Comment: Thanks - I have added the jar files from common and i get an error when I run the sumulator that they anot be found.  I'm new to eclipse - Have I missed anything?

Comment: I'd rather use the apache method but tried copying the code into a class - it has a few errors.

Comment: you are right the apache method is best, removed the source code to avoid confusion. thanks davy