# Encode a file in Base64 format - Blackberry/J2ME

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to upload a file to a http server, but first I need to encode this to a base64 format. How do I do that? I have open a fileconnection but i dont know how to encode the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a byte array to base64 for blackberry using Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753629/convert-a-byte-array-to-base64-for-blackberry-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

Since BlackBerry is a J2ME environment, you can't use regular J2SE clases such as sun.misc.BASE64Encoder - but there is a native [Base64OutputStream](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/Base64OutputStream.html) class which should serve the same purpose.  See the javadocs for more info.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer This doesn't change the fact that it's not available on BlackBerry or other java-me devices.  Marc is contrasting his answer with Mike's.

Answer (score 3):

See this java-me [Base64](http://vc.thauvin.net/cvs/BlueMonger/src/com/bluemonger/j2me/Base64.java?revision=1.1.1.1&content-type=text/plain&view=co) class for encoding with base64 format.

For more examples check [koders](http://www.koders.com/java/fid2B76F86B8F8FF984EFE3C04AC6DE198E40D8EF41.aspx?s=base64#L3) or this *Java and ME* blog post: [Base64 encode-decode in JavaMe](http://www.java-n-me.com/2010/12/base64-encode-decode-in-javame.html).

Comment: Although on the BlackBerry specifically there are Base64InputStream and Base64OutputStream classes (as of OS 4.6) that let you do this without having to use third-party classes. Either way will work.

Comment: FYI, the Base64InputStream and Base64OutputStream classes have been around for a long time - since 3.6.0 or 4.0.2 - it's only a new constructor for Base64OutputStream (with newlineTrigger) that was added in 4.6.

Answer (score -3):

If you're doing this in Java you can use the BASE64Encoder and write to a new encoded file:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File inputFile = new File(yourUnencodedFile);
        File outputFile = new File(yourEncodedFile);

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        encoder.encode(
            new FileInputStream(inputFile),
            new FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        );
```

and then just use the encoded output file

Comment: unfortunately that class isn't available in J2ME

Comment: That class isn't even part of the Java SE standard and using it makes your application unportable, even across different Java SE implementations (try running that code on the OpenJDK). And on non-Java SE JVMs (i.e. Java ME or Blackberry), you definitely have no access to it.

Comment: Yes I am very sorry OP, I saw the Java tag and answer above mine and though for some reason it was being done in Java (no more late night SO answers for me). and @Joachim thank you, I actually did not know that the sun packages were not supported in the public interface http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html so thank you for teaching me that